# Why did I get AttributeError?

Tags: python, attributeerror, feature-extraction

I tried to change a few lines from the original code however when I tried to run , I got error that say 'AttributeError: module 'PngImageFile' has no attribute 'shape'.
However, I had no problem when running the original code. What should I do to remove this error in my modified code?

Here is the original code :

```
from skimage.feature import hog, local_binary_pattern
from skimage.transform import pyramid_gaussian
from skimage.io import imread
import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from skimage import color
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import imutils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import glob
from sklearn import metrics
from PIL import Image # This will be used to read/modify images (can be done via OpenCV too)
from numpy import *

# define parameters of HOG feature extraction
orientations = 9
pixels_per_cell = (8, 8)
cells_per_block = (2, 2)
threshold = .3

# define path to images:
dataset_path = r"C:\Users\user\Documents\FYP\Dataset FYP\Train New\Contrast" # path of our dataset
    
# compute HOG features and label them:

for category in category_im_listing: #this loop enables reading the files in the pos_im_listing variable one by one
    im_listing = os.listdir(dataset_path + "/" + category)
    num_im = size(im_listing)
    print("There are " + str(num_im) + " images in category " + str(count + 1))
    for file in im_listing:
        img = Image.open(dataset_path + "/" + category + "/" + file) # open the file
        img = img.resize((150,150))
        gray = img.convert('L') # convert the image into single channel i.e. RGB to grayscale
        # calculate HOG for positive features
        fd = hog(gray, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm='L2', feature_vector=True)# fd= feature descriptor
        data.append(fd)
        labels.append(count)
    count = count + 1
```

Here is the code that I modified but got error :

```
    from skimage.feature import hog, local_binary_pattern
    from skimage.transform import pyramid_gaussian
    from skimage.io import imread
    import joblib
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    from sklearn import svm
    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from skimage import color
    from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
    import imutils
    import numpy as np
    import imageio
    from ipynb.fs.full.anna_phog import anna_phog
    import argparse
    import cv2
    import os
    import glob
    from sklearn import metrics
    from PIL import Image # This will be used to read/modify images (can be done via OpenCV too)
    from numpy import *
    
    image_path = r"C:\Users\user\Documents\FYP\me\train"
    
    #MODIFIED
    S = 8
    angle = 360
    Level = 3
    roi = [1,225,1,300]
    save=True
    
    # read the image files:
    category_im_listing = os.listdir(image_path) # it will read all the files in the path
    num_category_im = size(category_im_listing) # simply states the total no. of category
    print("There are " + str(num_category_im) + " categories") # prints the number value of the no.of categories dataset
    data= []
    labels = []
    count = 0
    
    # Modified : I deleted the resize and gray line, and change the fd line into p because I want to extract PHOG instead of HOG
    for category in category_im_listing: #this loop enables reading the files in the pos_im_listing variable one by one
        im_listing = os.listdir(image_path + "/" + category)
        num_im = size(im_listing)
        print("There are " + str(num_im) + " images in category " + str(count + 1))
        for file in im_listing:
            img = Image.open(image_path + "/" + category + "/" + file) # open the file
            # calculate PHOG for positive features
            p = anna_phog(img, bin, angle, Level, roi) #MODIFIED
            data.append(p)
            labels.append(count)
        count = count + 1
```

Here is the error that I get in my modified code:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-9e9360ca5082> in <module>
      8         img = Image.open(image_path + "/" + category + "/" + file) # open the file
      9         # calculate HOG for positive features
---> 10         p = anna_phog(img, bin, angle, Level, roi)# fd= feature descriptor
     11         data.append(p)
     12         labels.append(count)

~\Desktop\FYP\anna_phog.ipynb in anna_phog(Img, bin, angle, L, roi)
     11     "import cv2\n",
     12     "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"
---> 13    ]
     14   },
     15   {

AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

New Error (Updated) :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-00f72c361b79> in <module>
      8             img=cv2.imread(image_path + "/" + category + "/" + file) # open the file
      9             # calculate PHOG for positive features
---> 10             p = anna_phog(img, bin, angle, Level, roi) #MODIFIED
     11             data.append(p)
     12             labels.append(count)

~\Desktop\FYP\anna_phog.ipynb in anna_phog(Img, bin, angle, L, roi)
     35     "        E = cv2.Canny(G,lower,upper) #high and low treshold\n",
     36     "        GradientX, GradientY = np.gradient(G)\n",
---> 37     "        GradientYY = np.gradient(GradientY, axis=1)\n",
     38     "        \n",
     39     "        Gr = np.sqrt(np.square(GradientX)+np.square(GradientY))\n",

~\Desktop\FYP\anna_phog.ipynb in anna_BinMatrix(A, E, G, angle, bin)
     56     "    p = anna_PhogDescriptor(bh_roi,bv_roi,L,bin)\n",
     57     "    return p"
---> 58    ]
     59   },
     60   {

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

​
```

Comment: Replace `anna_phog(Image, bin, angle, Level, roi)` with `anna_phog(img, bin, angle, Level, roi)`

Comment: @enzo I tried to change that line, however I still got an attribute error but now it says 'PngImageFile' has no attribute 'shape'.

Comment: Then try replacing `anna_phog(img, bin, angle, Level, roi)` with `anna_phog(asarray(img), bin, angle, Level, roi)`

Comment: error shows problem inside function `anna_phog` but I don't see code for this function. It seems it is in some file `.ipynb` - maybe save it as normal `.py` or copy all `anna_phog` to this code

Comment: `.shape` can suggest that you use `numpy array` but you use `pillow` to load image `Image.open()` and it may need to convert to `numpy array` to use `.shape` - `np.asarray(img)`. OR use `cv2.imread(...)` instead of `Image.open()` and you get directly `numpy array` (but it needs to convert colors `BGR` to `RGB`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw [anna_phog](https://johnnn.tech/q/how-to-remove-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-builtin_function_or_method/) on other portal.

Problem is because this function needs `numpy array` but you read image with `pillow` `Image.open()` and you have to convert `img` to `numpy array`

```
img = np.asarry(img)
```

---

**EDIT:**

There will be other problem.

`anna_phog` converts colors `BGR2GRAY` because `cv2` gives colors in `BGR` instead of `RGB` - but `pillow` gives colors in `RGB`. So better use `cv2` to read image.

Comment: Thanks, I have change the line img = Image.open to img=cv2.imread, and there's no more attribute error. However, now I still get another error that said TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'.

Comment: this `ipynb` makes only problems - it doesn't show exactly where is this error. Normal `.py` should show line with `/`. It shows problem in `anna_BinMatrix` and I see `.../bin` and there is built-in function `bin()` and normally code `2/bin` generates the same error as you get. So problem can be variable `bin` in your code - you don't have `bin = ...` and it uses built-in `bin()`. You have to decide what you need to assign `bin =...` because I don't know what it should be.